# How do I change the size of grid cells to better fit its content?

Tags: css, css-grid

As you can see the content inside the grid cell does not fit the size of the grid cell. I am trying to change the size of the grid cell to better fit the content inside.

This is the code responsible for the grid:

```
main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(589.19px, 1fr));
    overflow-x: hidden;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

[image]

Comment: without your HTML... Try to change 1fr by auto

Comment: Please edit your question to add the HTML. See [mcve] for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your property `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(589.19px, 1fr));`, specifically `auto-fit` ensures the grid fills the space and doesn't leave empty space in the line.
You can use:
`grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(589.19px, min-content));` and in case `589.19px` is too wide for you maybe `repeat(2, min-content)` will work better.

The repeat function takes two arguments the first one is the **repeat count**. When set to auto-fit it repeats until the line is filled, if you set two 2 you repeat it twice.

Comment: what does the 2 do?

Comment: let me update the answer... in the meantime can you tell me if the code works?

Comment: It works, I should've specified in the main post that I am trying to emulate https://rickandmortyapi.com/ . So I am trying to get the same responsiveness that it has for my table.